# How to speed up this table view row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, performance

i use a table view with custom values and image.

**Every rows do this**:
- Check device (iphone/ipad)
- Parse a wordpress xml
- Split this string "Thu, 13 Jan 2011 22:26:27 +0000" and get pos[1] and pos[2].
- Convert "Jan" in "Gennaio"
- set values in row cell

It's make in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    @try {
        newsRow = ((NewsRowController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]);
        if (newsRow == nil) {

            if ( [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"] || [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
            else [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow" owner:self options:nil];

            if ([tableArray count] > 0) {               
                NSArray *chunks = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

                [newsRow setCellDataWithName:[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  
                                     andDate:[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                                         day:[chunks objectAtIndex:1] 
                                       month:[self convertMonthToExtended:[chunks objectAtIndex:2]]];
            }
        }       
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"OK, crashato. Sappiamo il perchè!");
    }

    return newsRow;
}
```

the function convertMonthToExtended do this:

```
if ([small isEqualToString:@"Jan"]) return @"gennaio";
[...]
if ([small isEqualToString:@"Dec"]) return @"dicembre";
```

Now, on simulator it works very fine, but on device, a 3G device in particular, when i scroll the table it scroll slowly because i do a lot of things.

How can i **speed up the scroll**?
What is correct way to **re-implement this function** to be more fast?
**How can i optimize this snippet?**

Any idea please?

thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can move the following code:

```
if ( [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"] || [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
            else [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow" owner:self options:nil];
```

Outside the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method because you don't need to do this check for every row (the device doesn't change from line to line). And you can put this code in `viewDidLoad` .

I suggest you do all the computations and the work of asynchronous network. 
You can precomputare all the information you need to populate the rows and save them in such a NSArray while viewing a UIProgressView or something like that, only after all the operations populate the table view.
You can use the `[Tableview reloadData]` method to reload all data in the table view, this mean that `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` , `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, and all the data source method are recalled.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought that it would be a better approach to batch process this information in chunks into an intermediate data store which would be used to back the UITableView, as doing the calculation within the cells themselves it what's causing the issues you describe. (Depending on the duration of the processing, you'll probably want to show a [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) whilst you're crunching the data.)

By doing this, you should presumably remove the need to process the XML data for every row individually, etc. and whilst this might not be significantly faster from a raw processing perspective, it'll at least feel faster from the user's perspective, which is probably the key issue.